# node & nodejs have different version

Tags: nodejs

I successfully update/install the latest version of node js by using those commands (the official `curl` way not working for me) :

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable

sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/<VERSION>/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

However, the version of my node and nodejs become different :

```
$ node --version
v5.0.0
$ nodejs --version
v0.10.25
```

It seems the new node is installed in `/usr/local/bin/node`, so i tried :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```

But it returns :

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/local/bin/node’: File exists
```

I also use this link :

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/node’: File exists
```

I will use some frameworks that depend on `node`, like `Ionic`. Which node version will it use?

What should i do to solve this?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: The real question imo is, how do I tell n to overwrite any existing node versions and symlink both `nodejs` and `node` to the binary installed by n. And if n is incapable of doing so, what is the state of the art approach? In a working environment it is very prone to error, if nodejs and node address different nodejs versions.

Answer (score 23):

Steps that solved the same problem for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs
```

**Explanation**

You have installed two versions of nodejs on your computer, so you need to remove one of them. Your situation:

```
node v5.0.0 - you will keep this one
nodejs v0.10.25 - this you can remove
```

You can remove `nodejs` package via `apt-get remove` command. This will also remove the file `/usr/bin/nodejs` and you will not get your error message again.

Now you can create a symbolic link called "/usr/bin/nodejs", that points on source "/usr/local/bin/node". In your example you have wrong order of paths "from" and "to"

```
sudo ln -s source_file myfile
```

More info about links creation: [How symbolic links works](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abbe)

Answer (score 8):

The error:

`ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/node’: File exists`

is normally caused when you really have two versions of the Nodejs, a with the alias of the `node` and the other with the `nodejs` alias, as we can see on the result of the commands `node --version` and `nodejs --version`:

```
$ node --version
v5.0.0
$ nodejs --version
v0.10.25
```

so you can't create a symbolic link for a file that already exists.

To solve this you need to completely remove the two packages using:

```
sudo apt-get purge node
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
sudo rm -rf bin/node bin/node-waf include/node lib/node lib/pkgconfig/nodejs.pc share/man/man1/node
```

and reinstall only the `nodejs` package using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

and create a symbolic link using:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

or install the `nodejs-legacy` that will resolve this problem with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Comment: thanks a lot, you added the information, I already solved the issue by myself. I upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

For me the `node` command is the NodeJS installed by `nvm` and `nodejs` command is the NodeJS installed using `apt-get`

Comment: That was also my problem on Ubuntu 16.04. Fixed with `sudo apt remove nodejs && nvm install --lts node`.